# How to convert object all value to number of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have a object and i want to convert it to be like number of objects

see this is a object -

```
[{
    "type_width": "245",
    "type_height": "60",
    "type_size": "21"
}]
```

and want to convert this object like:

```
[{ "Type Width": "245"},{"Type Height": "60"},{"Type Size": "21"}]
```

Comment: No, you probably don't want that (as it makes little sense to have that datastructure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let arr = [{ "width": "245","height": "60","size": "21"}]
    
let op = Object.entries(arr[0]).map(([key,value]) => ({[key]: value}) )

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to iterate the objects, and flatten the results to a single array. Convert each object to an array of key/value pairs with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the pairs to an object.

```js
const data = [{"width":"245","height":"60","size":"21"}]
    
const result = data.flatMap(o => // iterate the objects and merge the results to a single array
  Object.entries(o) // convert each object to an array of key/value pairs
  .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v })) // convert each pair to an object
)
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a variable already :

```js
let obj = [{
  width: "245",
  height: "60",
  size: "21"
}]
    
console.log(
  Object.keys(obj[0]).map(k => ({[k] : obj[0][k]}))
)
```